# how to use nested scrollviews with delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have used two scrollviews,one for horizontal and second for vertical scrolling. I am using scrollViewWillBeginDragging delegate method. When I scroll in horizontal direction, vertical scrollview does not show imageview.

Help me.

Comment: Please give us more info. We really can't work with this kind of limited info to solve your problem. Please describe and explain it better.

Comment: Why two nested scroll views?  Why not one scroll view with two scroll bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not it is a good idea to nest scrollviews is a different question, but generally you have two scrollviews and check which one is dragging. In your scrollViewWillBeginDragging to the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     if (scrollView == horizontalScrollView) {
          // handle horizontal scrolling
     else if (scrollView == verticalScrollView) {
          // handle vertical scrolling
     }
}
```

Comment: I have used this approach but when I scroll horizontal and then vertical, it always moves in if block instead of else if. I also used tags but faced same problem.